# How to change Postfix to IPv4 or IPv6

Tags: email

I was trying to allow IPv4 or IPv6 in my postfix, but I keep getting error's no matter where I put...

inet_protocols=ipv4

Where do I put it?

Comment: I hope you can edit this to make a clear question. what's error display ? what have you done ? maybe you can read [this](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` should contain

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
inet_protocols = all (DEFAULT)
inet_protocols = ipv6
inet_protocols = ipv4, ipv6
```

see `man 5 postconf` for further information

The entry "all" is equivalent to "ipv4, ipv6" or "ipv4", depending on whether the operating system implements IPv6.
IPv6 may accept implicit IPv4 on  systems  that  pre-date IPV6_V6ONLY support, else IPv6 only is meant.
"ipv4, ipv6" supports both protocols, depending on OS with separate server sockets.
It also sets the behavior for outgoing connections. (AAAA,A)

More details, os specific and postix-version-specific things are described in the man page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your answer would be improved if you described what the code you've posted does (e.g. "the first line is the file you need to edit, these lines need to be changed, further information is available in...", or something similar).